# This webpage is not available in imap_header function call

Tags: php, imap

I have some php lines which reads an email from gmail inbox by using imap extension functions.

My code is :

```
$mbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}', 'myemail@gmail.com', 'mypassword')  or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$header = @imap_header($mbox, 99) or die (imap_last_error());

print_r($header);

imap_close($mbox);
```

When i call imap_header with a number other than 99 it works well, bu it does not produce any output or error by 99. Why?

**UPDATE : The Message header in my email inbox can be read by imap_fetchheader**

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `99` is probably linked with your specific box: for me it works for 99 :-).
If you want to further investigate the cause of the error, you should post here the error produced, too :-)

Comment: no error produce, in chrome it writes "This webpage is not available"

Comment: So with "it explodes by 99" you mean it does not produce any output? If you feel it should produce some output (the code you posted does not produce any output, even if it does not explode ;-), you should chech web server logs, it's there where you find php errors...

Comment: I this case even blank white page does not appear after running code ! Explode = no blank page and no error :) . I have updated the question. Where can I see the server logs?